# Why Is InterruptedException a Checked Exception?

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown

When working with threads in Java, dealing with InterruptedException seems to be a particular thorn in my side.  I appreciate the fact that it's thrown when my threads are terminated, and thus offers me a chance to cleanup.  What seems odd to me is that it's not an *unchecked* exception.

This creates the following problems:
a) If I want to use an existing framework in my threaded app, I'm *forced* to convert it to an exception the framework interface accepts.  Thus the framework generally misinterprets it instead of either cleaning up or propagating it as it should.

b) Unless InterruptedException is rigorously declared for every call in the stack (and it's usually not because of a) ), it's difficult to cleanly shutdown.

If InterruptedException were instead unchecked, it seems that it would have a much higher likely hood of being used properly and resulting in clean shutdown of threads and apps in general.  Why isn't it?

Comment: I would imagine the decision to make this exception checked vs unchecked came down to visibility while implementing a multi-threaded solution.  Sort of a "hey, you should really pay attention to this and get it right." thing.  Enforcing this at compile time forces the implementer to at least think about the issue of being interrupted.  Making it unchecked would have moved the visibility of this issue below the horizon.

Comment: Voted for closing because except for the ones who specified it, we can only make an educated guess.

Comment: (а) is a problem with your framework, not with `InterruptedException` per se. (b) `RuntimeException` signals a programming error; `InterruptedException` is not a result of a programming an error.

Comment: InterruptedExceptions are particular complicated to handle, when they happen you need to care about the interrupt flag of the thread, and it can only happen in blocking operations. For that it is a quite good reason to actually make it checked.

Comment: @eckes: I don't see how whether or not an exception is complicated to handle has any bearing on whether or not it should be checked.

Comment: Because you might catch it by accident and handle it wrong - or in case of seldomly happening IE, you might forget to handle it in a retry loop.

Comment: BTW, I typically use the simple rule: if I dont know how to handle it IE and dont want to rethrow it, I finish early and set the interrupt flag again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interruption is supposed to be cooperative. I think the designers wanted to avoid a situation where you could blow away a thread by interrupting it, where the thread didn't have code to handle that eventuality. The intention seems to have been to make the Runnable code explicitly decide how to handle interruption. A lot of framework or language code seems to be about deciding whose responsibility something should be, and trying to make the correct usage apparent, in order to minimize how badly users get burned. This is one of those judgment calls.

With InterruptedException being checked, the worst case is that the exception is caught, but in a way that isn't awfully useful. (Actually the absolute worst case is the interrupt flag is not restored, leaving any following code in the thread unaware that the interruption happened.) If InterruptedException was unchecked (or if you wrap it in a RuntimeException, as shown in the article linked in the comments), the exception could go unhandled and proceed to terminate the thread, which could be really bad if the thread was not at a stopping place.

Toy examples and simple code would work better with unchecked InterruptedExceptions; nobody would bother with catching the exception and it would just work. However, in real code doing substantial work this was probably considered detrimental.

Making the exception checked is an attempt to ensure that the developer knows the exception can be thrown so that the developer can avoid the situation where the exception gets thrown in the middle of work the thread is doing, potentially leaving the work partially-done in a bad state.

Comment: I agree interruption is supposed to be cooperative.  If the exception were however unchecked, it offers a 'best-effort' compromise.  You can either do your best to cooperate, or ignore it, but either way your going to be shutdown rather than potentially keep running in a wonky state.

Comment: @Andy: there would be good points to it. I'm not a fan of checked exceptions at any rate.